how can I handle this challenge with S3 indicating Orange color

I am new in this field and needs help
PC-A is able to communicate with R1, R2, R3. however, the communication can proceed to S3, S2, Pc-B, PC-C.
In Switch S3, I see the orange color how can i fix this. I need your help. I will be available to share further information for you to assist me. Thank you

Looks like Packet Tracer...
That orange symbol indicates a blocked link by a spanning tree protocol. Since there are multiple links between switches/bridges, one of them needs to be blocked to avoid a network loop which would cause a broadcast storm.
You can 'avoid' the block by deactivating spanning tree, but then a broadcast storm would quickly bring down the network. Alternatively, aggregate the ports using LACP or a static setup.

Zac67 Thank you for the guidance. I truly Appreciate it.

Please don't forget to eventually accept an answer. (And you may vote for any useful ones, too.)
